# How to make the type of input password when the user actually selects the input box?

Tags: html, forms, passwords

This is the code I have already. When the box is inactive it displays the text"Password". I would like when the box is selected it removes the "Password" text and displays the users input as dots like a password field.

```
<div class="custom"><input type="text" class="custom" size="12" value="Password" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Password') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Password'; }"/></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the type via JS the same way you've changed the value:

```
<input type="text" class="custom" size="12" value="Password" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Password') { this.type = 'password'; this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.type = 'text'; this.value = 'Password'; }"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you're just looking for:

```
this.type = 'password'
```

and conversely:

```
this.type = 'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by setting the type of the input to 'password'.  If you want to display a label for the field in the value, i would recommend using the [JQuery watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/).  It effectively does what i believe you are attempting to code out, but won't ever submit the word 'Password' as the value of the form field.